# Are there annuities to be paid prior to patent grant but to maintain the patent application in the United States?

Tags: patent-applications, fees, united-states, maintenance-fee, fee

Are there annuities to be paid prior to patent grant but to maintain the patent application in the United States?

CHATGPT says No.

But, https://www.quantifyip.com/blog/article6.aspx says yes.

Comment: ChatGPT generates text, and does not check whether any facts it puts in  are actually true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like most countries.

Many countries require annual
payments to keep a patent application alive while it is pending and then more annual payments to keep a patent in force. They are called *annuities* or *renewal fees*.

The U.S. does have *[maintenance](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/fees-and-payment/uspto-fee-schedule) fees* due only after grant. They are due at three points: 3,5, 7.5 and 11.5 years after the date of grant in order to keep a U.S. patent enforceable.